# rowReorder JQuery Datatables, get clientX

Tags: jquery, datatables

Is it possible to get the clientX from a DataTables rowReorder event?

This is a small code snippet from what I'm trying to do:

```
table.on( 'row-reorder', function ( event, rows, nodes ) {
 console.log(event);            
});
```

Currently from this, I get that the clientX and clientY are undefined.

Is there any work around for this?

I will really appreciate any help.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: It is a custom event created and triggered by DT, not derived from a native `MouseEvent` interface and thus lacking `clientX` and so on. What do you need it for?

Comment: Am working on a table where some rows are child rows, and with the reordering I want to be able to tell whether the dropped is is to be a child row using the distance from the left hand side to the exact location to which it is dropped